# Configure coding style in IntelliJ-Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA the curly brackets are as positioned as follows:

```
/**
 * 
 * Created by MaximusDecimus on 2/23/2017.
 */
public class StackOverflowMWE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Tomorrow is Friday! Yippee Kay Yay Mother Sugar!");
    }
}
```

I am more used to this:

```
/**
 *
 * Created by MaximusDecimus on 2/23/2017.
 */
public class StackOverflowMWE
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Tomorrow is Friday! Yippee Kay Yay Mother Sugar!");
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can opt this in IntelliJ IDEA. Or do I have to do it manually? The PyCharm is based on the second style as shown above which is again by Jetbrains the same people of IntelliJ.

Comment: That's standard java code style, I recommend keep using that, but if you really want to change, you can change it at settings.

Comment: you can find the settings at Editor -> Code Style -> Java

Comment: if that's the case I will use the recommended style. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Android Studio, but here's where to set this setting there:

Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Braces Placement -> select "Next Line"